# UIAppearance of UILabel whithin UICollectionViewCell - selected/unselected

Tags: swift, uiappearance

I am currently working with `UIAppearance` for the colors of all my outlets on my project, which allowed me to create my own "DIY" version of a nightmode on my iOS app.

sample :

```
UILabel.appearance().textColor = colorScheme.primaryColor 
UILabel.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [MyController.self]).textColor = colorScheme.secondaryColor 
...
```

*Note: Colorscheme is just a struct with all my colors, that switch depending on the state .lightMode / .darkMode*

I recently build a subclass of `UICollectionViewCell` with a `UILabel` inside, and I wanted to use the same method to define the colors within it. However I am troubling to figure out **how to set a different color for the nested UILabel depending on the selected state of the Cell**.

For instance :

```
// create a default UIView with specific backgroundColor 
let selectedBackgroundView = UIView()
selectedBackgroundView.backgroundColor = colorScheme.selectedBackgroundColor

MyCollectionViewCell.appearance().backgroundColor = colorScheme.backgroundColor // default 
MyCollectionViewCell.appearance().selectedBackgroundView = selectedBackgroundView // set specific view used when cell is selected
```

This code above works fine when I want to set different background colors when `MyCollectionViewCell` is selected or not, however I want the nested `UILabel` to change its `fontColor` as well, depending if the cell is selected or not. Is there a propper way to achieve this with `UIAppearance`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found a Workaround for this issue. I post my solution it may help someone.

first I define the color for both `textColor` and `highlightedTextColor`

```
UILabel.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [MyCollectionViewCell.self]).textColor = colorScheme.color1
UILabel.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [MyCollectionViewCell.self]).highlightedTextColor = colorScheme.color2
```

Then in `MyCollectionViewCell` I "bind" the `isSelected` to UILabel `isHighlighted` :

```
class MyCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var myLabel: UILabel!

    override var isSelected: Bool {
        didSet {
            self.myLabel.isHighlighted = isSelected
        }
    }
}
```

Works flawlessly.

Hope this can help someone